# PHP/MySQL - Select One of Each Type In Table

Tags: php, mysql, select

I'm creating a blog with many different categories and on my home page I'd like to show one post from each category (except maybe "miscelanious") but I'm not sure if there's a simple one line solution for this.  I'm hoping for something along the lines of:

```
"SELECT * FROM blogs WHERE cat != 'misc' ORDER BY added LIMIT (ONE OF EACH CAT TYPE)"
```

Is something like this possible?

Comment: `group by category`?

Answer (score 5):

Just `GROUP BY` the category -

```
SELECT * 
FROM blogs WHERE cat != 'misc' 
GROUP BY cat
ORDER BY added
```

Comment: This would still fetch all entries and not only one per entry (although it display only one per entry) and hence could take longer on a large table than manually getting one via LIMIT? Or is my thinking wrong?

Comment: It does fetch them all, but will show one per category. The one it shows could be random though. Since we really don't know what the OP wants as output it would be hard to say beyond this.

Comment: Thanks @JayBlanchard, it does show only one of each category type.  I would ideally like it to show the latest one, ie. `order by 'added' desc`

Comment: If `added` is a date you can select the `MAX()` added date and then perform the group by. It's hard to know for sure without seeing your table config.

Comment: Thanks @JayBlanchard, I tried to add MAX() but it gave me an error (`Warning: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in`) so I've reverted back to using it without!

Comment: OK - I'll remove from answer.

Comment: @JayBlanchard, Thanks - However I would like it to order by the date as currently it's showing everything older than newer :(

Answer (score 1):

You can try this way `GROUP BY` your category. see more about `GROUP BY` https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html

```
SELECT * FROM blogs WHERE cat != 'misc' GROUP BY cat ORDER BY added
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to find the newest entry in each category, you're going to have to figure out which entry is newest, then join to back to it -- you can do this with a subselect, if necessary:

```
SELECT b.* 
FROM blogs `b`
INNER JOIN (SELECT `category`, MAX(`added`) AS `max_add` FROM `blogs` GROUP BY `category` WHERE `category` != 'misc') `a`
ON `a`.`category` = `b`.`category` AND `a`.`max_add` = `b`.`added`
```

(or something similar -- best to join on a PK if possible)

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7745609/sql-select-only-rows-with-max-value-on-a-column) gives a pretty detailed response to the general problem.