# Make only one query to get data from the same table

Tags: mysql

What the best way to make only one call to the DB in this case :

```
query="""SELECT measure FROM data 
         WHERE id =%s AND pId = %s AND data_type ='total' 
         ORDER BY createdAt DESC LIMIT 1;"""
lines = self.cursor.execute(query,(id,pId))

query="""SELECT measure FROM data 
         WHERE id =%s AND pId = %s AND data_type ='tot_m' 
         ORDER BY createdAt DESC LIMIT 1;"""
lines = self.cursor.execute(query,(id,pId))
```

Works fine but are made 2 queries to the table. What best way to do the in one query ? Thx in advance and sorry for my english...

Comment: is this python-mysql library?

Comment: yes...........:)

Comment: @George see my new answer below if that works for you please upvote

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP/MySQL - Select One of Each Type In Table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29776933/php-mysql-select-one-of-each-type-in-table)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
query="""SELECT measure FROM data 
         WHERE id =%s AND pId = %s AND data_type ='total' 
         ORDER BY createdAt DESC LIMIT 1;
         UNION
         SELECT measure FROM data 
         WHERE id =%s AND pId = %s AND data_type ='tot_m' 
         ORDER BY createdAt DESC LIMIT 1;"""
lines = self.cursor.execute(query,(id,pId))
```